# Why is Gmail stripping styles from elements

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I've been through a number of solutions online. I've used EmailOnAcid to fix errors and sent that output to Gmail with no errors.

I'm generating our output through a series of loops to generate a data table and recommendations so I am using the same styling on each like element. When I look at it in Gmail, a couple of cells have the styles stripped. It makes absolutely no sense.

[image: Sample of cell formatting]

I've added spaces between the properties. I've removed spaces between the properties. I've rewritten the styles. Just keep getting the same result.

Here is the html for the th and td.

```
<th style="padding: 16px !important; text-align: center !important; font-size: 12px !important; border: none; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff !important; background: #0173b1 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">{{label}}</th>

<td style="padding: 16px !important; text-align: center !important; background: #e7f2fa !important; font-size: 14px !important; border: none; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff !important; color: #2f4f4f !important;">
```

Pretty simple stuff.

On the cells in the image without formatting, all of the style information is gone.

```
<th>Nitrite</th>
```

I'm hoping somebody can provide some direction.

Comment: Have you tried to debug using the developer tool in the browser? I think you can check why does it has the stripping style.

Comment: All I can see in dev tools is that the HTML tag has had the style stripped. By the time it's in my inbox, all of the processing is complete.